# Polymer data binding json object

Tags: json, binding, polymer

I have an issue with the polymer two-way binding with json object

An input binding with a simple var , 2 way binding works \o/

With an object, {{message.from}} for example :
--> the input modify the variable {{message.from}}, no problem

BUT :

if in a function i modify the var message.from the input is not populate with this change

Input is not refreshing

Thanks

```
<template>

    <style is="custom-style" include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment iron-positioning">

    </style>

    <div class="vertical layout center-justified">

        <div>
            <div>{{session.user.name}}</div>
            <div>{{session.user.id}}</div>
        </div>


        <div class="horizontal layout center-justified">
            <paper-button on-click="envoi" style="margin-top:20px;">
                <iron-icon icon="send" item-icon></iron-icon>
                VALIDER</paper-button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template> 


<script>
addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
        Polymer({
            is: "creation-dossier",
            properties: {
               session: {
                    type: Object,
                    value: function() { 
                        return { 
                            user: { 
                                name: "rob",
                                id: 1 
                            } 
                        }; 
                    }
                }
            },
            envoi: function(){
               console.log('this.session.user.name '+ this.session.user.name);
               console.log('this.session.user.id   '+ this.session.user.id);
               this.session.user.name = "coucou2";
               this.session.user.id = 0;
               console.log('this.session.user.name '+ this.session.user.name);
               console.log('this.session.user.id   '+ this.session.user.id);
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please elaborate. What are the expected and actual behaviors?

Comment: I modify the snippet

In fact i would like to know why the var content is not refreshing in the view .

If i use a single var, no problem.
But with object, not the same success.

Thanks for your opinion

Comment: do you want the changes made inside envoi function to be reflected in UI ??

Comment: The solution was to use this.set('xxxxx', 'yyyy') instead of this.xxxx = '"yyyy"

Answer (score 0):

This is because polymer does not observe sub property changes.
If you have a property like this

```
session{value:10}
```

and if you do `this.session = 20;` it will be reflected to UI automatically by two way binding.

for sub-property changes you can make use of `notifyPath` like this.

```
`envoi: function(){
    this.trail = 20;
    console.log('this.session.user.name '+ this.session.user.name);
    console.log('this.session.user.id   '+ this.session.user.id);
    this.session.user.name = "coucou2";
    this.session.user.id = 0;
    console.log('this.session.user.name '+ this.session.user.name);
    console.log('this.session.user.id   '+ this.session.user.id);
    this.notifyPath('session.user.name', this.session.user.name);
    this.notifyPath('session.user.id', this.session.user.id);
 },`
```

or the other way is to make use of `dirty-checking` like this

```
`envoi: function(){
    this.trail = 20;
    console.log('this.session.user.name '+ this.session.user.name);
    console.log('this.session.user.id   '+ this.session.user.id);
    this.session.user.name = "coucou2";
    this.session.user.id = 0;
    console.log('this.session.user.name '+ this.session.user.name);
    console.log('this.session.user.id   '+ this.session.user.id);
    var temp = this.session;
    this.session = [];
    this.session = temp;
 },`
```

third way is making use of `set` like this
    `this.set('session.user.name','some name');`